# No option to add a google account in Android AOSP

Tags: android, android-emulator, account, android-source

I'm having trouble with a recent Gingerbread AOSP build as I cannot add a google account in the settings -> accounts & sync menu.  It seems like the option isn't there: I can add an exchange account, but not a google account.  When I click on Add account, it goes to the Add an Exchange account screen, instead of letting me choose which kind of account I want to add (google or exchange).

My build is on Ubuntu 10.10 32-bit with Sun Java 1.6.0_24, so it is a **32-bit** build, which is non standard for gingerbread, but I managed to get it to work using the instructions on the google site, as well as the instructions in this thread (http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/b0bb991131589363?pli=1).  Other than that it is the stock emulator (lunch 1).  I haven't tried the other configurations so I don't know if the problem repeats across them all.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

IG808

Answer (score 3):

Google's proprietary applications are not included in AOSP. You'll have to find them elsewhere and install them to your device.

Comment: do you know which gapp(s) is responsible for this? i am trying to add it to an emulator build but i can't seem to find more info on which exact gapp apks enable this feature.